# Traveling to Spain from the USA with an Italian permanent residence card

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, eu, us-permanent-residents

I have travel coming up from New York to Spain. I am wondering if I will need a visa considering that I am:

- an Italian permanent resident (I have the *permesso di soggiornno CE*)
- a US permanent resident
- a citizen of Ghana

I know I can travel within the Schengen area, but how does it work when traveling from outside the EU? Is my point of entry to EU from other continents always going to be Italy, or I can enter another Schengen county like Spain from the USA?

Comment: What is your citizenship? And do you have permanent residence in both the US (as your [tag:us-permanent-residents] tag implies) and Italy (as you stated in the body of the question)?

Comment: @200_success Yes, I have both US and Italian permanent residence but my actual citizenship is Ghanaian. Parents immigrated to Italy and then to the US. Living in the US now but I have a work trip coming up in Spain.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're not already visa exempt due to your nationality. Then [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) states that as an Italian resident, you will not need a visa:

> **Visa Exemptions**:
>
> Passengers with a residence permit issued by Italy for a maximum stay of 90 days. The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.
>
> Passengers with a valid D visa issued by Italy for a maximum stay of 90 days. The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.

So there are no restrictions on where to enter the Schengen area with your Italian residence permit, but you can stay in other Schengen countries for at most 90 days in a 180 day time period.

Comment: You just show your passport and blue card when you check in for your flight. No problem.